# Android WebView navigating event?

Tags: android, navigation, xamarin, android-webview

I'm looking for the event of a Android WebView that is equivalent to the "Navigating" event of a WPF WebBrowser, or the "ShouldStartLoad" of a IOS UiWebView.

I found "shouldOverrideUrlLoading", but I don't know how to use it because the constructor needs an URL...

I would like to intercept the Url before navigating, and cancel the navigation for some URLs...

I'm using Xamarin in Visual Studio.

WPF equivalent :

```
webBrowser.Navigating += WebBrowserNavigating;

private void WebBrowserNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (//condition)
        e.Cancel = true;
        //Do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should use the *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* method. This method is called automatically, so you don't have to worry about the parameters.
In order to use this method, you have to create first a WebViewClient like this:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         ...
      }
}
```

And then, you set it as your WebViewClient:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

When the *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* method is called you'll receive by parameter the WebView and the URL that is going to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have an other question : is there an equivalent to "UIWebView.EvaluateJavascript" or "WebBrowser.InvokeScript" ?

Comment: There's this method: webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); but I don't think it's the same thing

Comment: @Gab i am also struggle with that place xamarin forms webview navigated method get response token get successfully in androdi but in iOS i am getting passed URL value only after login clicked . what problem there. are u have solution let u tell me