# Fill website data and click button and parse response

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want to let users enter the vehicle number and then read the data and show the vehicle details to the user. I don't want to do it in a webview. I am able to fill the data using this code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcstatus.xhtml");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String reg1="KA51X";
                String reg2="2442";
                 if(isFirstLoad) {
                     webView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                             "document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no1').value = '" + reg1 + "';" +
                             "document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no2').value = '" + reg2 + "';" +
                             "var frms = document.getElementsByName('convVeh_Form');" +
                             "frms[0].submit(); };");

                     isFirstLoad = false;
                 }
            }
        });
```

Here is the website which shows the data for this app.

https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcstatus.xhtml

Now I am trying to click the submit button using this line

```
 "frms[0].submit(); };");
```

and this,

```
"javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:j_idt21').click();})()"
```

but they are not working. How to click the button whose Id is

> convVeh_Form:j_idt21

Also, once able to click the button, the response will come from the website. How to read that response text and put it in textview of app.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee

Comment: I want to know how to run that JS in my code.

Comment: @Akshat Gave you a few alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a separate problem you're having, `convVeh_Form:j_idt21` is just a label (at the time of writing). You want `convVeh_Form:j_idt27`. Maybe they changed?

You may want to style your injected javascript and selector as `document.querySelector('[id="convVeh_Form:j_idt27"]').click()`.

This gets around the `:` being a special character for purposes of a css selector.

```java
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcstatus.xhtml");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    String reg1 = "KA51X";
    String reg2 = "2442";
    if (isFirstLoad) {
      webView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
        "document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no1').value = '" + reg1 + "';" +
        "document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no2').value = '" + reg2 + "';" +
        "document.querySelector('[id=\"convVeh_Form:j_idt27\"]').click(); };");

      isFirstLoad = false;
    }
  }
});
```

You could also use `button[type="submit"]` as the selector if you know it'll always be the first button, such that the Ids no longer matter. (Maybe they will change again?)
The other fields would be `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')[0]` and `[1]`.

Once the form is submitted, the navigation will change. This triggers an event you can hook by subclassing the WebView. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560555/android-webview-navigating-event) for the other question for an example.

```java
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Use that as your event, detect the URL at the endpoint, and then inject some new javascript to extract the information from the page. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.! Now trying reading data from the table. :) :_

Answer (score 2):

As I figured out correct id is `convVeh_Form:j_idt26` instead of

> "javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:j_idt21').click();})()"

Please, check my [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/JohhnyCosmic/folders/Jing/media/fab68896-613c-4fad-a8d3-84d4470896fe/2016-10-05_1815.png) to prove it

So, my main suggestion is to test your JS code in browser before adding it to Android. Debug mode in Chrome is really good for that, I am sure you know how to enable it.

After that if you sure that JS code works well, please add code to Android by logical blocks. That can help you to debug it.

For example first of all put following lines of the JS code:

> document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no1').value = 'text'
>          document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:tf_reg_no2').value = 'text'

If you saw the result on the device you should add click event then.

> document.getElementById('convVeh_Form:j_idt26').click()

It can separate your JS logic and you will be sure what actually wrong with code.

Regarding to this line:

> Also, once able to click the button, the response will come from the website. How to read that response text and put it in textview of app.?

You should implement own `WebViewClient()` and override`onPageFinished`and run JS code only on the correct page.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcstatus.xhtml".equals(url)) {
        // run JS
    } else if("response_link".equals(url)) {
        // notify user or any other logic
    }
}
```

Good luck!

P.S. All JS code above works well in browser on my side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but the solution given in the accepted answer seems good as any change in button ID wont effect it. +1 for the working answer though.

Answer (score 0):

How to click the button whose Id is convVeh_Form:j_idt21

```
$('#convVeh_Form:j_idt21').click();
```

How to read that response text and put it in textview of app.?
If it is a submission of the form, then it would be easier for this message to use ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://your.url",
})
.done(function( data ) {
   $('#textview').text(data);
});
```